# I am trying to use module requests in python and it is simply not working

Tags: python, python-requests, spss

**My issue**

i have downloaded chardet, requests, typing, binary io, and django modules in an effort to fix whatever issue i am having while importing python module requests.
I also reainstalled python with the standard group of python modules option. I dont know what the issue is please help. Thank you.

**Further information**

Python 3.9

Installed using pip

**The code:**

import requests

**Below is the error log:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SPSS\STATIS~1\26\Python3\Lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 12, in <module>
    import chardet
ImportError: No module named 'chardet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SPSS\STATIS~1\26\Python3\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SPSS\STATIS~1\26\Python3\Lib\site-packages\requests\exceptions.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import JSONDecodeError as CompatJSONDecodeError
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SPSS\STATIS~1\26\Python3\Lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 14, in <module>
    import charset_normalizer as chardet
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SPSS\STATIS~1\26\Python3\Lib\site-packages\charset_normalizer\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .api import from_bytes, from_fp, from_path, normalize
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SPSS\STATIS~1\26\Python3\Lib\site-packages\charset_normalizer\api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from typing import BinaryIO, List, Optional, Set
ImportError: No module named 'typing'
```

Comment: How did you install those libraries?

Comment: What version of Python is this? The "No module named 'typing'" error makes me a bit suspicious that it's Python 3.4 or earlier.

Comment: Please follow this guide to ask questions that assist others in helping you:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I used pip to install. And python 3.9

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the code that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue after checking everything using pip. All modules up to date python up to date pip up to date. However despite completely uninstalling and reinstalling setuptools was out of date. so i updated setuptools with pip.

to find out whats out of date with pip:
`pip list --outdated`